# Reporting Services Authentication issue

Tags: authentication, reporting-services, azure

I am trying to programmatically render a PDF using Azure Reporting Services. I suspect that the actual PDF retrieval is fine, but I cannot find a way to authenticate the connection before requesting the report (via URL). I am working in the services layer of my web application and I cannot use a web reference (might not work with Azure) and it doesn't make sense to use a ReportViewer control (since it's a service layer method).

I have all the details to connect, but I suspect that I require a cookie to authenticate and I'm not sure how to manually create this. Any suggestions/solutions?

Here's my code so far:

```
string userName = BJConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ReportingServiceUsername");
string password = BJConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ReportingServicePassword");
NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
Domain.Report report = GetReportById(id);

int timeout = 30; //seconds
string url = "https://bleh.ctp.reporting.database.windows.net/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?...";
string destinationFileName = "@C:\\Temp.pdf";

// Create a web request to the URL
HttpWebRequest MyRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
MyRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
MyRequest.Credentials = networkCredential;
MyRequest.Timeout = timeout * 1000;
try
{
    // Get the web response -- THE RESPONSE COMES BACK AS UNAUTHENTICATED...
    HttpWebResponse MyResponse = (HttpWebResponse)MyRequest.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the section titled "SOAP Management Endpoint Programmatic Access":
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/771e88b6-ab0f-4910-a5fa-5facd8d56767#SOAPManagement.
It explains how to authenticate using a cookie container without a ReportViewer control.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is going to work.  Azure Reporting uses Forms Authentication and as I understand it, you aren't going to be able to match the Forms Auth cookie along with the MachineKey for encryption.

Comment: So are there any other ways to go about retrieving pdfs in code without report viewer and without a reference to the reporting service? Surely there must be a way to authenticate if I've got the full URL, the username and the password. IF it can be done manually, there must be a way to do it programatically?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to accomplish the same task..but using a WebRequest was impossible.
I changed the approach using a ServerReport class like this:

```
ServerReport report;
report = new ServerReport();
report.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(reportServerName + "/ReportServer");
report.ReportPath = "/ReportPath";
report.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportServerCredentials();
report.SetParameters(new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("param1", param1));
report.SetParameters(new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("param2", param1));
return report.Render(reportParams.OutputFormat);
```

The ReportServerCredentials class must implement the IReportServerCredentials interface like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg552871.aspx#ReportsandReportViewer).

More info about the IReportServerCredentials interface and implementation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.ireportservercredentials%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).